# Creating a tensor variable with a dynamic shape

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am a newbie to tensorflow. I have a tensor `score` and I am trying to create a tensor variable with the shape `score.shape[0]`.

```
score = tf.constant(np.array([[10, 0, -5], [4, 3, 0], [-3, 0, 11]]), 
dtype=tf.float32)
v = tf.Variable(tf.zeros(tf.shape(score)[0]))
```

But I am getting the error: `ValueError: Shape must be rank 1 but is rank 0 for 'zeros_2' (op: 'Fill') with input shapes: [], [].`. Was wondering where I am going wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just use `score.shape[0]` to get the first dimension of the `score` tensor:

```
sess = tf.InteractiveSession()
score = tf.constant(np.array([[10, 0, -5], [4, 3, 0], [-3, 0, 11]]),dtype=tf.float32)
v = tf.Variable(tf.zeros(score.shape[0]))

tf.global_variables_initializer().run()
v.eval()
# array([ 0.,  0.,  0.], dtype=float32)
```

`tf.shape` returns a tensor which needs to be evaluated before you can use it:

```
sess = tf.InteractiveSession()
score = tf.constant(np.array([[10, 0, -5], [4, 3, 0], [-3, 0, 11]]),dtype=tf.float32)

v = tf.Variable(tf.zeros(tf.shape(score).eval()[0]))

tf.global_variables_initializer().run()
v.eval()
# array([ 0.,  0.,  0.], dtype=float32)
```